# SWIFT: Retrieve data from Parse and append it to a key value dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I've retrieved data from Parse, and I'd like to append it to a Dictionary in the following format -

```
var guests = ["Event 1": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2", "Guest 3"], "Event 2": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2"], "Event 3": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2"], "Event 4": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2"]]
```

Using the following code, I have been able to retrieve the following data successfully, but I'm having issues figuring out how to append it to the dictionary -

[image]

```
  //Retrieve guestlist data
    let query = PFQuery(className:"GuestList")
    query.whereKey("Family", equalTo: "Family 1")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {

                //print(objects)
                //self.objectArray.removeAll()

                for object in objects {

                    //what code should I add here to append the object values into the dictionary
                    print(object)

                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        } else {

            print(error)
        }

    }

    }

}
```

There are four events in which a specific guest can be invited to (represented by a true / false in the "(eventName)RSVP" columns). IF a guest is invited to an event (i.e. the "(eventName)RSVP" is true), I would like it appended to the dictionary). My questions are:

1. How would I define the dictionary?
2. What code would I use to append the retrieved data into the following 'key value' dictionary format? -

   var guests = ["Event 1": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2", "Guest 3"], "Event 2": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2"], "Event 3": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2"], "Event 4": ["Guest 1", "Guest 2"]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
    func retrieveGuestlist() -> [String : [String]] {

        var guestList = [String : [String]]()

        let eventList = ["Hindu", "Reception", "Sangreet", "Tibetan"]
        for event in eventList { guestList[event] = [String]() }

        let query = PFQuery(className:"GuestList")
        query.whereKey("Family", equalTo: "Family 1")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let family = objects {
                for guest in family {
                    for event in eventList {
                        if let invited = guest.valueForKey("\(event)RSVP") as? Bool {
                            if invited {
                                guestList[event]!.append(guest.valueForKey("GuestName") as! String)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print(error)
        }

        return guestList
    }
```